# export data in datagridview to excel sheet windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, export-to-excel

I have `DataGridView` and when I display export to excel sheet button following error appeared:

```
(Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018  (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD)))

here
(
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
)
```

and this reference which I used 
(Microsoft excel 12.0)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0; 

        for (i = 0; i <= DGData.RowCount  - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= DGData.ColumnCount  - 1; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = DGData[j, i];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error might be because the user local settings are different from the office version, the solution below might work for you, try it and let us know what happens:

Before creating Excel object

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

After closing Excel:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

  releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
  releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
  releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Exceptions Appearing on these lines