# How to Export datagridview to excel file

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagirdview data with 5 columns include 1 columns `id` and 4 columns text. Besida that, I was exported to excel file but it just show 5 records while my datagridview have more records. How can I export to excel file with condition datagridvew just have 1 record, 3 records... I have a code, could anyone help me? :

```
 private void Btnexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save as Excel File";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File(2003)|*.xls|Excel File(2007)|*.xlsx";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                excel.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i =0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count;i++ )
            {
                for(int j=0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    excel.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

                }
            }
            excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
            excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            excel.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [export data in datagridview to excel sheet windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202861/export-data-in-datagridview-to-excel-sheet-windows-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply change the **2nd** for loop's **Columns** to **Rows**, and the exported data will be right. Besides, do you guarantee all the cells are not empty? If empty, ToString() will throw exception.